# How to perform an action after, or send information in res.redirect('/')?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, download, middleware

Background Information

- I am working on a NodeJS w/ Express project.
- I am using some auth middleware, we can call it `isAuthenticated()`
- The middleware is just protecting certain routes w/ passport, etc.
- I am adding a file download link that is visible when a user is not authenticated yet. (i.e. the button is publicly visible).
- If you click the button, the download route is protected, so we redirect you to a sign in page.

The Problem

- Once the user authenticates, I am calling `res.download(file);`. The download works fine, but the user is still at the sign in page with their credentials typed in. (Note: the user is authenticated, but no further redirect is happening on this route). If I try `res.download(file)` and then make a call to `res.redirect('/')`, the file isn't downloaded.

Basically: I want to redirect the user to the home page at `'website.com/'`, but the approaches I've taken haven't worked.

**Main Approach:**

- Set `res.local.downloadFile2 = true` in the `router.get('/download/file2')` route. Then redirect to home using `res.redirect('/')`. Now, in the home route, I would just do the following after rendering the home page again.

```
if (res.locals.downloadFile2 === true) { 
    res.download(file2) 
}
```

**However**: `res.locals.downloadFile2 === undefined` when that check is being done. I've tried to step through and somewhere it is being reset in one of the _modules I am using, so this is not working. I am currently unsure of the cause.

I could probably *solve* this by not displaying the links until a user is Authenticated, then there *shouldn't* be any cases of redirecting to login and back again, which means they would never see the login page, etc. but that is not the right solution to this problem, and is not the one I want to implement.

I would really appreciate any help, and can provide more information if needed!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that after the redirect, the `res` object is a complete new object due to the browser issued a new request to follow the redirect. That's why `res.locals.downloadFile2` is `undefined`.

To solve your problem, you can replace your code `res.local.downloadFile2 = true` with code to set a cookie. The cookie holds information which will be stored on client side by the browser and send to the server with every request.

See [cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies) npm package for example:

```
var Cookies = require('cookies');
var cookies = new Cookies(req, res, { keys: ['arbitrary string to encrypt the cookie'] })    

// get value of the cookie
var need_to_download_file = cookies.get('need_to_download_file', { signed: true })

// Logic to download file (if necessary)
if (need_to_download_file) {
    // Trigger download of the file
    // Reset cookie
    cookies.set('need_to_download_file', false, { signed: true })
}

// set the cookie 
cookies.set('need_to_download_file', true, { signed: true })
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'll have to look into this a little more tomorrow, but will reply and accept tomorrow!

Comment: I am now successfully setting the cookie in my `'/download/file'` route, and reading the cookie in my `'/'` route, however it appears I cannot use res.download() & res.render('/') in the same request, so I am still stuck being unable to download the file. How would I go about getting the file to download after I have redirected the user back to the homepage? I thought about making the middleware be the homepage redirect, that way after the main page is rendered we would download the file, but I'm not sure that will work the way I think it will. Any further advice?

Comment: One approach is to only call `res.render()` and within the rendered page, provide a javascript block which opens the link to the route `/download/file2`. Make sure the javascript block only gets inserted / executed if `need_to_download_file` is `true`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on this, and I appreciate all the help you've given me so far. To accomplish what you suggested, I'm trying to add a `window.open()` call in my `onLoad` event for the HTML body. I'm calling `window.open('localhost:3000/download/file2', '_self')` but it is not working. I'm checking the cookie for every call to that route now `router.get('/download/file2')` and if the cookie exists and === true, I download the file then reset the cookie, otherwise I set the cookie to true and redirect to the home page where I am hoping that the onLoad event will work. Any further advice?

Comment: Please check your browsers webdeveloper tools for errors in JS console. Also check the network tab to verify that there is a request to `/download/file2`.

Comment: I was looking for an error but didn't see any. The network tab shows the request as being canceled. I'm unsure why it's being canceled. I'll make another post for this issue since you've already solved the main problem that I had when I originally created this post.